# How to migrate/move GitHub Teams across different Orgnaizations (in GHE)

Tags: github

We have a new GitHub Organization created and need to migrate/move our current Org's Teams (including the members in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider scripting that migration through [GHE API](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.15/).

- either through [organization](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.15/v3/orgs/)
- or through [members](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.15/v3/orgs/members/):

  - getting the list of members of the old org
  - adding them to the new one
- [Teams](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.15/v3/teams/) (same idea, for Team members)